How to debug/trace Spring PreAuthorize annotation
I have spring boot application. I am trying to follow the official spring tutorial from here https://github.com/spring-attic/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/
or specifically this class:
https://github.com/spring-attic/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/blob/main/security/src/main/java/com/greglturnquist/payroll/EmployeeRepository.java
What I found is, that PreAuthorize annotation works for delete method, but does not work for save. For example:
@Override
@PreAuthorize("#employee?.manager == null or #employee?.manager?.name == authentication?.name")// This does not work
Employee save(@Param("employee") Employee employee);

@Override
@PreAuthorize("#employee?.manager?.name == authentication?.name") // This does work
void delete(@Param("employee") Employee employee);

when I say "does not work", I mean that I can send HTTP request and perform the save operation, but for delete, if I send HTTP request I get 403 error, how it supposed to be.
I tried to copy the PreAuthorize annotation from delete method, that save and delete has absolutely the same annotation, but still does not work.
If I enable full Spring tracing, I found this in the logs (I removed some long package names.):
Delete method is not authorized
horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Authorizing method invocation ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public abstract void com....EmployeeRepository.delete(com.greglturnquist.payroll.Employee); target is of class [jdk.proxy2.$Proxy120]
horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public abstract void com....EmployeeRepository.delete(com.greglturnquist.payroll.Employee); target is of class [jdk.proxy2.$Proxy120] with authorization manager org.....DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager@55fb1217 and decision ExpressionAuthorizationDecision [granted=false, expressionAttribute=#employee?.manager?.name == authentication?.name]

but for the save with the same object and same expression log looks like this (call is authorized)
horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Authorizing method invocation ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public abstract com.greglturnquist.payroll.Employee com....EmployeeRepository.save(com.greglturnquist.payroll.Employee); target is of class [jdk.proxy2.$Proxy120]
horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Authorized method invocation ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public abstract com.greglturnquist.payroll.Employee com....EmployeeRepository.save(com.greglturnquist.payroll.Employee); target is of class [jdk.proxy2.$Proxy120]

So, the question is how to debug it first? I tried to debug it, but then I ended up somewhere in this class org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression which is a generic Spring expression evaluator and it is quite difficult to see, how it evaluates the expression. What I want to see, what are the values of each annotation expression which is used there. For example, this one
@PreAuthorize("#employee?.manager?.name == authentication?.name")
what is the value of #employee?.manager?.name and authentication?.name. But what I got in the logs is only the expression itself and only when it was not authorized. In case of successful authorization, I do not see anything, no expression, no values.
And maybe someone had this problem in the past and knows why it happens.
P.S. the link I put above, use quite old version of Spring. I upgraded it and I am using the latest version.

The delete passes the preauth if the Employee object has a Manager of the user calling the delete.
Think of it like, I can only delete employees that I manage.  So if you're signed in with the user whose username is "greg", then you cannot delete the employees managed by, "oliver"...to use the users defined in that tutorial.
The save passes the preauth if the Employee's Manager is null or if its Manager is the authenticate username.
Think of it like, I can either assign myself as the Manager, or leave it as null.  If I try to create an employee assigned to a different manager, it will fail.
So, with those rules now well-understood, here's what you can do.  Signed in as greg, you can delete Frodo, Bilbo, and Gandalf.  You can save additional employees where you assign yourself as the Manager, or leave the Manager null.  You cannot delete the Employees of "oliver" or save new employees with him as the manager.
As far as how you debug it, well, you've already found it.  The SpEL is all there is.  If that SpEL evaluates to false, the preauthorize fails.  But really, you shouldn't have to debug that, boolean conditions are usually pretty easy to understand.
Here's a test to illustrate how Spring does this:
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.expression.EvaluationContext;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SpELTest {

    @Test
    public void parseSpell() {
        // Create a manager named bob and assign it to an employee
        Manager manager = new Manager();
        manager.setName("bob");

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setManager(manager);

        // Create a mock user with the username of "bob"
        SecurityContext securityContext = mock(SecurityContext.class);
        when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("bob", ""));

        // Create the EvaluationContext using the Spring Security Context as its root object.
        // To get the authentication class, this root object needs to have a getAuthentication method on it
        // Spring Security configures this context for evaluating SpEL expressions.
        EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(securityContext);

        // Add the employee variable to the context.
        context.setVariable("employee", employee);

        // Now you have the context that contains the employee object and authentication, parse the expression

        // In this case, employee's manager is bob, and the authentication return's "bob" satisfying the second part of this boolean
        assertEquals(Boolean.TRUE, new SpelExpressionParser()
                .parseExpression("#employee?.manager == null or #employee?.manager?.name == authentication?.name")
                .getValue(context, boolean.class));

        // replace the employ in the context, with a new Employee -- null Manager
        context.setVariable("employee", new Employee());

        // In this case, employee's manager is null, satisfying the first half of this boolean
        assertEquals(Boolean.TRUE, new SpelExpressionParser()
                .parseExpression("#employee?.manager == null or #employee?.manager?.name == authentication?.name")
                .getValue(context, boolean.class));

        // Create a negative test, create employee with manager other than bob
        Manager otherManager = new Manager();
        otherManager.setName("tom");
        Employee otherEmployee = new Employee();
        otherEmployee.setManager(otherManager);
        // Replace the employee in the context
        context.setVariable("employee", otherEmployee);

        // In this case, employee's manager is tom and the authentication user is bob, failing the second half of this boolean
        assertEquals(Boolean.FALSE, new SpelExpressionParser()
                .parseExpression("#employee?.manager == null or #employee?.manager?.name == authentication?.name")
                .getValue(context, boolean.class));
    }
}

Hope this helps.

Thanks a lot for the explanation. Especially the test code is very useful.
The thing is, that based on the javascript/React code, the logic is a bit different than you described. Save can only be done by the manager and on the client side update employee button is hidden, if it is not my employee.
I think the proper statement is like this:
"I can only delete or save employees that I manage."
This is what I am expecting or I want to achieve.
I tried the same PreAuthorize for save/delete and it works for delete and not for save.
P.S. I think I put a bit different code. I updated it now.

@Zlelik I'm not sure what you mean that the logic is different.  PreAuthorize has nothing to do with the client, it's all server-side processing.

In this file https://github.com/spring-attic/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/blob/main/security/src/main/js/app.js there is a client validation of the same thing. It does not matter. This is how I understand your point:

User greg can only delete employee where manager is greg
User greg can update any employee if greg is logged in to the application. even if employee has manager oliver, greg can still update employee.

What I want to have:

same as you said.
User greg can update employee where manager is greg (same condition as for delete) and this does not work.

